# What model is this strange airplane-helicopter combination?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification

I'm a local historian in Fort Collins, CO and I'm trying to find out anything I can about the helicopter/plane image in the attached picture. The only thing I know is that it was parked in a early Fort Collins airport.

[image]

Comment: I believe that's called an autogyro.  The rotor operates in "autorotation" I.e. It is unpowered.

Answer (score 24):

It is a [Pitcairn PCA-2 autogiro](https://dmairfield.com/airplanes/NC10780/). From the linked article:

> This aircraft is a Pitcairn PCA-2 autogiro, S/N B-12 (ATC #410), manufactured in April 1931 by Pitcairn Aircraft, Inc., Willow Grove, PA. It came from the factory with a Wright J-6 engine (S/N 12528) of 300HP. It had a Hartzell steel propeller.  It was a three-place craft, weighing 3,000 pounds.

Apparently, the aircraft was owned by [Amelia Earhart](http://www.aviation-history.com/airmen/Amelia-Earhart-Autogiro.htm) and sponsored by Beech-Nut packing company.

> NC10780 was sold to George Palmer Putnam, husband of Amelia Earhart, of New York, NY on May 7, 1931.  This autogiro is the “older” (by a week) sister ship of NC10781 flown through Tucson by John M. Miller.

Comment: That's some mighty fine sleuthing!